# Jquery - capture keyup event when tab/window is not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to play/pause music with the keyboard's play/pause button when the tab/window is not in focus. (Google Play Music does this). The code I am currently using is:

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 179) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }
});
```

Is there a way to capture the `keyup` and run the function when the tab/window is out of focus?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible.

Comment: @Kolby How does the Google Play Music website accomplish this then?